# Controller of components based on array input (React native)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build Controller of Reports where it routes to detail component based on the state.reports of the child components

My concept is like this

```
 1 - render the top level of array 
 2 - each array element is clickable and call function **route**
    - if element has children set state to child array and go to step 1
    - else go to detail page
 3 - if we are at child array we show **back button** that can return to previous render.
```

Here's my Controller

```
export default class ReportControler extends React.Component {
  state = {reports: [] }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.parent = null;
    this.path = [this.constructor.name];
  }

  route = (report) =>{ 
    if(report.children) return this.moveToChild(report);
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ReportDetails', this.path.join('/') + '/' + report.title);
  }

  moveToChild = (report) => {
    this.parent = this.state.reports;
    this.path.push(report.title); 
    this.setState({reports: report.children});
  }

  moveToParent = () => { 
    this.setState({reports: this.parent});
    this.parent = null;
    this.path.pop();
  }

  render(){ 
    const reports = this.state.reports.map(report => (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => { this.route(report) }} >
        <View><Box title={report.title} image={report.image} /></View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback >
    ));

    let back = null;
    if(this.parent){
      back = <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.moveToParent} >
        <View>
          <Text style={{color: '#274496', fontSize: 20, padding: 10, borderBottom: '#274496', borderBottomWidth: 2 }}>{this.path.join(' / ') }</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback >
    }

    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        {back}
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
          {reports}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The children Component would work like this

```
export default class Leads extends ReportController {
  state = {reports: [
        {title:"Campaign", image: require('../../assets/Report/bullhorn.png') },
        {title:"Status", image: require('../../assets/Report/analysis.png') },
        {title:"Source", image: require('../../assets/Report/wind-turbine.png') },
        {title:"Location", image: require('../../assets/Report/route.png') },
        {title:"Device", image: require('../../assets/Report/responsive.png') },
        {
          title:"Time", image: require('../../assets/Report/statistics.png'), 
          children: [
            {title:"Days", image: require('../../assets/Report/statistics.png')},
            {title:"Hours", image: require('../../assets/Report/statistics.png')},
          ]
        },
    ]
  }
}
```

My issue now is on the moveback function.
This function won't work for more than 2 level
How to set `this.parent` array?

```
moveToParent = () => { 
    this.setState({reports: this.parent});
    this.parent = null; //Here I should set the parent array  
    this.path.pop();
  }
```

Comment: I dont have code example but a general idea on how to do this. Best way would be to make it recursive if you want it to work for unknown levels of Parent, Child relationship. Try something like using ReportControler inside ReportControler. Send down the data to ReportControler as props, render chart if the data you got is not an array of reports, if it is an array pass it again to ReportControler inside ReportControler. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. I have the same thought but I am still not finding the way to control back button

Comment: Back would be easier if you are maintaining the state in url, you can just use browser back.

Comment: Each ReportControler at every level should maintain a flag and pass down a method to flip that flag from detail to list and list to detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to fix the parents by storing them in array

Here is what I did

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.parents = [];
    this.path = [this.constructor.name];
  }
  moveToChild = (report) => {
    this.parents.push(this.state.reports);
    this.path.push(report.title); 
    this.setState({reports: report.children});
  }

  moveToParent = () => { 
    const reports = this.parents.pop();
    this.setState({reports});
    this.path.pop();
  }
```